# Number of strings on the set N4 that are of length 10 and contain seven ones.

Tags: combinatorics

Sample Question 10.
Let N4 = {1, 2, ..., 4}.

A) Calculate the number of strings on the set N4 that are of length 10.

B) Calculate the number of strings on the set N4 that are of length 10 and contain seven ones.

The answers are:
A) 1048576
B) 3240

I know A is 4^10, gives me 1048576

but i have no clue how to get B, any help, so i can plug it in on a calculator?

Comment: When you say "contain seven ones" do you mean exactly seven or at least seven?  The answer indicates exactly seven, per Rustyn, but you need to be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretend your string of ten digits chosen from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is 10 bins organized in a line. 
Ten choose seven = 120 is the number of ways to place seven ones in 10 bins. Now the other entries can be 2,3, or 4 so this yields 3 possibilities for each of the three other bins. Hence $$3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot {10\choose 7} = 3240$$

Comment: Thank you, makes a bit more sense, Though, im not sure why it yields 3 possibilities for each of the three other bins

i mean if it was N4 = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
it would simply be the count of N4 - 1? so 5 possible?



3^3*(120) right?

Comment: 3 other possibilities for the other bins because none of the bins can have a 1